# multiple conditions np.where

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to use np.where with two conditional statements but I am getting

ValueError: The truth of a Series is ambiguous.  Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), or a.all().

My code looks like this:

```
df[column4'] = np.where(df['column1'] > df['column2'] and df['column1'] > df['column3'], df['column1'], np.nan)
```

I have tried this with '&' and 'and' operators to no avail

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Use `&` and you need parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chain the condition like

```
df['column4'] = np.where((df['column1'] > df['column2']) & (df['column1'] > df['column3']), df['column1'], np.nan)
```